# Why js from a file in tests does not work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, integration-testing

I have a small test to check the appearance of an select by pressing the checkbox.

The js code is in a separate file. If start the server and check manually, everything works.

I also include this file in application.js

But in the test this file is not connected.

**If I insert js code directly into the html code, then everything works again.**

My js file:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('#checkme').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#interval').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $('#interval').css('display', 'none');
    }
  })
});
```

My test:

```
assert_not page.has_select?(:interval) #true
page.check('Checkme')                 #true
page.save_and_open_screenshot(full: true) #screenshot
assert page.has_select?(:interval) #false
```

In the screenshot I received, I see that the checkbox is active, but js does not work.

Comment: it seems that the link to the JS file is not done properly. can you post a screenshot with the folder structure and the path from your HTML index file to the JS file itself?

Comment: @GabrieleMagno But js connects in the developer environment when I start the server. Does this mean that the file is referenced correctly?
I also tried to write js code directly in the application.js file. In the application itself, the code works. But it doesn’t work in tests.

Answer (score 1):

**This was due to precompile assets.** 
I deleted the public/assets folder, where I had old compiled js files.